# How to get string from arrays in PHP (Foreach)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I want to get the results of the array using foreach. But what I get is only 1 array, even though before using Foreach, there are 9 arrays. 
How to get a string from the results of the 9 arrays that I listed below?

I use PHP version 7.0 with the Laravel 5.0 framework. $paramsUserId will be filled with a specific user_id for example '10729'

```
private function itemNotReco($paramsUserId = null)
{
    try{
        $result = DB::connection('read')->table('recommendation_events')
            ->where('user_id', $paramsUserId);

        if ($result) {
            $result = $result->distinct()->get(['item_id']);
        }

        foreach ($result as $re){
            $re = $re->item_id;
        }
        return $re;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $log = ['Service' => 'RecommendationEventService', 'function' => 'getItemNotRecommendation'];
        logError($e, $log);
    }
}
```

Result (using Postman):

```
"77178"
```

Below is the result of the 9 arrays that I got without using foreach with the code like the following

```
private function itemNotReco($paramsUserId = null)
{
    try{
        $result = DB::connection('read')->table('recommendation_events')
            ->where('user_id', $paramsUserId);

        if ($result) {
            $result = $result->distinct()->get(['item_id']);
        }
        return  array_column($result, 'item_id');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $log = ['Service' => 'RecommendationEventService', 'function' => 'getItemNotRecommendation'];
        logError($e, $log);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
array:9 [
  0 => 77196
  1 => 77263
  2 => 77202
  3 => 77262
  4 => 77275
  5 => 77259
  6 => 77345
  7 => 77329
  8 => 77178
]
```

The results I want are like this (using Postman)

```
"77196", "77263", "77202", "77262", "77275", "77259", "77345", "77329", "77345", "77329", "77178"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only return 1 data since `return` stops on the first loop. There are two ways to solve your problem:

**1.** Use `echo` instead of `return`.

**2.** Store the data in a new variable like this:

```
private function itemNotReco($paramsUserId = null)
{
    try{
        $result = DB::connection('read')->table('recommendation_events')
            ->where('user_id', $paramsUserId);

        if ($result) {
            $result = $result->distinct()->get(['item_id']);
        }

        $data = [];
        foreach ($result as $re){
            $data[] = $re->item_id;
        }
        return $data;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $log = ['Service' => 'RecommendationEventService', 'function' => 'getItemNotRecommendation'];
        logError($e, $log);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_push`

```
private function itemNotReco($paramsUserId = null)
{
    try{
        $result = DB::connection('read')
                   ->table('recommendation_events')
                    ->where('user_id', $paramsUserId);

        $item_ids = [];
        if ($result) {
             $this_contain_item_ids = $result->distinct();

             foreach($this_contain_item_ids as $id){
                   array_push($item_ids, $id['item_id']);
             }
        }
        return  $item_ids;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $log = ['Service' => 'RecommendationEventService', 
                 'function' => 'getItemNotRecommendation'];
         logError($e, $log);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I found an error when using the code from you in this section
foreach($this_contain_item_ids as id){
                   array_push($item_ids, id->item_id);
             }
thanks for your help !

Comment: I just forgot the `$` sign.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get a string from the results of the 9 arrays that I listed
>   below?
>
> The results I want are like this
>
> ["77196", "77263", "77202", "77262", "77275", "77259", "77345",
>   "77329", "77345", "77329", "77178"]

What I understand you want to convert your result array into a [JSON](https://www.json.org/) string mentioned above. Try [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
if( $result ) {
   $result = $result->distinct()->get(['item_id']);
}
$arr = array_column( $result, 'item_id' );
return json_encode( $arr );
```

If your desired result is array instead of string then you may have achieved your goal. When you print_r/var_dump an array, it shows array indexes(0,1,2,3...) as well in result.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the **implode** function to achieve this :

```
$a = [111,222,333,455,5123,1116,713,811];

$b = implode(',',$a);

print_r($b);
```

**Before implode :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 111
    [1] => 222
    [2] => 333
    [3] => 455
    [4] => 5123
    [5] => 1116
    [6] => 713
    [7] => 811
)
```

**After :**

```
111,222,333,455,5123,1116,713,811
```